# What is the Print3D deviceType on Windows Print-Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, printing, windows-10

I've been working with Get-Printer and I ran into a situation where the server returns two instances of every print device. One is called "Print" and the other is "Print3D". I can't find any information about this online and I'm wondering what this device type is supposed to be used for.

**Bonus:** How do you turn this off and what impact does it have on printing?

Running Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

I asked Microsoft about this and I'm told it's a feature of Windows 10. As for why a regular printer shows as a 3D printer, still unknown. Could be a bug in the get-printer cmdlet.

> When the devicetype is Print3D it means the hardware support for 3D
>   printing is provided by the Printer hardware. With 3D Builder, you can
>   scan, construct, and print 3D models in Windows 10.

- Model and print 3D objects -
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4003696/windows-10-model-and-print-3d-objects
- 3D printing partners -    https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/3d-print/printing-partners

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation: you logged on via RDP to this server from a Windows 10 computer and didn't turn off the option to connect local printers; as a result, print drivers from the client got installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question recently. I used below code

```
get-printer -computername targetpc | where-object{$_.devicetype -eq "print"}
```

I hope it helps